# Alphanumeric usernames and error message for it

Tags: username, errors

I'm facing a problem where I haven't seen proper answer anywhere.
What I need help with is this:

How can I prevent my users registering non-alphanumeric usernames?
To be exact, I could prevent it by using something like:

```
function validate_alphanumeric_underscore($string?) { return preg_match('/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*$/',$str); }
```

But what is the string I should/could use and how can I echo error message saying that the username inputted had invalid characters?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Check for alphanumeric

For more details, look at the [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) Q on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex).

```
$name = 'input string 123";
// Doesn't allow:
// Pre-/Appending white space
// Not more than one space in between
// Non-alphanumeric characters (lower case)
if( ! preg_match( "/^[a-z0-9]+([\\s]{1}[a-z0-9]|[a-z0-9])+$/i", $name ) )
{
    // Output Error Message
}
// Or: Does only allow
// Alphanumeric character (lower & upper case)
// Dash & underline "-", "_" - makes (imho) sense
if( ! preg_match( "/^[A-Za-z0-9-_",'\s]+$/", $name ) )
{
    // Output Error Message
}
```

#### Error Message

You need to do this via Ajax. Best would be to [look over the search results](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=ajax+login). Another (maybe) good reference would be to inspect the code of some ajax login plugins for a "how-to".